# What is the difference between cuda-toolkit-10-1 and nvidia-cuda-toolkit when I install it on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, cuda, tensorflow

## Background of my questions

I have an old Lenovo ThinkPad W530 laptop with NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [[Quadro K1000M] / Quadro K1000M/PCIe/SSE2 GPU](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-k1000m.c1425) which is with [compute compatibility 3.0](https://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-NVIDIA/Quadro_K1000M.html) and is [supporting CUDA](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/quadro-k1000m/37629/2). I want to build some TensorFlow examples and project on Ubuntu for my Udacity nanodegree.

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and upgraded my NVIDIA drivers so when I execute `nvidia-smi` it gives me the following result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K1000M       On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   59C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    496MiB /  1999MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                              
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      5470      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7504      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                146MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7772      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              147MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     34770      G   /proc/self/exe                    158MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As I am trying to build the TensorFlow Code using GPU support, I found out that I need to install CUDA and follow [this article](https://medium.com/@paulrohan/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-20-04-f6f67745750a) about how to install latest version of CUDA 11.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. I went through the whole path and then I found out two problems:

1. My GPU is only support Compute Compatibility 3.0 while the minimum support for TensorFlow is 3.5
2. To overcome problem 1, I have to build the tensor flow from sources to get a build that supports CUDA 3.0 and to do that I have to use CUDA 10.1 which means I have to start from the beginning.

I removed CUDA 11.0 following the [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#removing-cuda-tk-and-driver). I started to install CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and now I got confused.

CUDA 10.1 [installation documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#removing-cuda-tk-and-driver) process is about installing CUDA 10.1 from a `.deb` file for Ubuntu 18.04 and there is no support for CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

So I started to follow the same steps of [the article](https://medium.com/@paulrohan/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-20-04-f6f67745750a) but for CUDA 10.1 instead CUDA 11. I was able to install cuda 10.1 using the command:

```bsh
sudo apt-get -f install cuda-toolkit-10-1 cuda-libraries-10-1
```

so that I don't override my installed NVIDIA driver 450 (I did that after several trials).

When I tried to execute command

```bsh
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

It gave me errors due to dependency problems. To overcome these errors I searched for a solution and then I came across [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d) which is recommending that:

> For the sake of being verbose, do not try to use 18.10 or 18.04 CUDA 10.1 for Ubuntu 20.04. I learned that the hard way, lol!
>
> So, you can install CUDA 10.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 by running,
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
> ```

I uninstalled CUDA Toolkit 10.1 that I installed using [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#removing-cuda-tk-and-driver) and I followed this recommendation and the command passed successfully. But now I am not sure if this is it, or am I missing something?!

When I tried to know the different between both ways I found out that the source of `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` using the command

```
apt-cache policy nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

it gives me the following result that indicates that the source is the Ubuntu repositories

```
nvidia-cuda-toolkit:
  Installed: 10.1.243-3
  Candidate: 10.1.243-3
  Version table:
 *** 10.1.243-3 500
        500 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

### My Questions

1. If the official installation documentation of CUDA 10.1 for Ubuntu 18.04 as well as CUDA 11 for Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't indicate any thing regarding installing the package of `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` so what is the difference between `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and `cuda-toolkit-10-1`?
2. Is it enough as indicated by [the article](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d) to only install `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` if I am trying to use CUDA toolkit 10.1?
3. Is CUDA 10.1 runtime libraries are now installed? If not, How can I install them right now? should I remove the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` or can I follow the steps from the documentation?
4. How can I validate my installation?
5. When I tried to build [CUDA Samples](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/cuda-samples/index.html#getting-cuda-samples), didn't find the `cuda-install-samples-10.1.sh` file in my installation. How can I install the samples?

I have been working on trying to build my examples and so far I failed to do that, so I really appreciate your support for this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a solution, I don't have the answer, but I can point you to a couple to resources that do:

- [Installing CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://medium.com/@stephengregory_69986/installing-cuda-10-1-on-ubuntu-20-04-e562a5e724a0)
- [Installing CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 to support older GPU cards](https://area-51.blog/2021/05/26/installing-cuda-10-1-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-support-older-gpu-cards/)

For posterity sake, these are the steps  (*kudos to Stephen Gregory*):

## 1. Clean up

(a) Open a terminal window and type the following three commands to get rid of any NVIDIA/CUDA packages you may already have installed:

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-*

(b) Purge any remaining NVIDIA configuration files and the associated dependencies that they may have been installed with.

sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

(c) Remove any existing CUDA folders you may have in /usr/local/

> This threw me for a loop the first several times I tried installing CUDA. There shouldn't be any folders with the name "cuda" or "cuda-anything" in usr/local/ at this point!

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*

## 2. Install

(a) Setup your CUDA PPA. (Read [here](https://itsfoss.com/ppa-guide/) if you're curious about what a PPA is.)

> Essentially, we're adding CUDA to our sources.list, which is the file that's referenced any time we use the apt package manager to download stuff in the terminal with a command like "sudo apt update"

sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-driverssudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pubsudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list'sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda_learn.list'

(b) Install CUDA 10.1 packages, including the CuDNN library

sudo apt update
sudo apt install cuda-10-1
sudo apt install libcudnn7

## 3. Add CUDA to PATH

(a) After installing, we need to add CUDA to our PATH, so that the shell knows where to find CUDA. To edit our path, open up the '.profile' file using vim.

sudo vim ~/.profile

(b) Finally, add these lines to the end of the file.

## set PATH for cuda 10.1 installation\

if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/" ]; then
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi

## 4. Reboot

(a) Reboot your computer (as you should after any driver install)

## 5. Final Check

Now, let's check to make sure everything's set up!

(a) Check NVIDIA Drivers:

nvidia-smi

(b) Check CUDA:

nvcc --version

(c) Check CuDNN

/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 2>/dev/null | grep libcudnn